# Can anyone help me with replace genesis post excerpt with yoast meta description and if there is no meta description show the excerpt?

Tags: child-theme, excerpt, genesis-theme-framework, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

Hellow,

I did replace the genesis post excerpt with the yoast meta description in my child theme, but the problem is, I want to show the post excerpt when there is no meta description again. the function I used is this,

```
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'genesis_do_post_content' );
add_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'excerpt_to_meta_desc' );

function excerpt_to_meta_desc(){

if ( is_singular() ) {
    the_content();

    if ( is_single() && 'open' === get_option( 'default_ping_status' ) && post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'trackbacks' ) ) {
        echo '<!--';
        trackback_rdf();
        echo '-->' . "\n";
    }

    if ( is_page() && apply_filters( 'genesis_edit_post_link', true ) )
        edit_post_link( __( '(Edit)', 'genesis' ), '', '' );
}
elseif ( 'excerpts' === genesis_get_option( 'content_archive' ) ) {


        if($output=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', true)){
        add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'replace_post_excerpt_filter' );

            function replace_post_excerpt_filter($output) { 
                return $output;
            }   

            echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', true) .'&nbsp; <a href="' . get_permalink() . '" class="excerpt_more">Read&nbsp;More</a>';
        }
        else{
            the_excerpt();
        }

}

else {
    if ( genesis_get_option( 'content_archive_limit' ) )
        the_content_limit( (int) genesis_get_option( 'content_archive_limit' ), genesis_a11y_more_link( __( '[Read more...]', 'genesis' ) ) );
    else
        the_content( genesis_a11y_more_link( __( '[Read more...]', 'genesis' ) ) );
   }
}
```

Its working just fine in my localhost, But causing fatal error when in online  domain.
something like this,  "Cannot redeclare replace_post_excerpt_filter() (previously declared in...."

http://clientproject.twramz.org/

I have checked all files , This is the only function where I am using this excerpt filter. Is there any solution, please?

Comment: Hello, I think you'll need to ask this one at the Genesis support forum.

Answer (score 1):

Remove:

```
 add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'replace_post_excerpt_filter' );

        function replace_post_excerpt_filter($output) { 
            return $output;
        }
```

from your code, and you should find it works.

The trouble with nested functions, as you have here, is that once the parent function is called the first time, it defines the inner function, but when the parent function is called the second time (in this case, when another Genesis entry is shown on an archive page or with a posts widget), then it tries to define the inner function again, but that causes a fatal error as PHP doesn't allow that.

In this case, you're filtering the excerpt, but not doing anything to the value passed into the filter function except immediately returning the original value i.e. the filter does nothing. As such, you can remove the redundant filter and it's callback, and that should fix the negative side-effect.